# Pesquisa e inserção não funcionam juntos - Flask

Tags: python, flask

Olá, estou fazendo um trabalho que necessita inserir valores no banco de dados, retorná-los em uma tabela e poder deletá-los através de Flask. Estou conhecendo a ferramenta e não consegui encontrar soluções. Conseguir fazer a inserção em uma página e a visualização e deleção em outra, tudo funcionando corretamente, mas o problema vem quando junto em uma única página, onde passa a funcionar apenas a inserção.

Esta é a parte do HTML:

```
<table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">LINK / IP BLOQUEADO</th>
                <th scope="col">REMOVER</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for row2 in listaIpLinks %}
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{row2.0}}</th>
                <td>{{row2.1}}</td>
                <td>
                    <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('deleteIpLink', id=row2.0) }}">
                        <input type="submit" value="Delete"></i>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

    {%from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
    <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('ipLink') }}">
        <dl>
            {{render_field(form.ipLink)}}
        </dl>
        <p><input type="submit" value=Register></p>
    </form>
```

Aqui está a parte responsável pelo Flask:

```
@app.route('/getIpLink/', methods=["GET","POST"])
def ipLink():
form = ipLinkForm(request.form)
try:
    if form.validate():
        ipLink = form.ipLink.data
        mycursor,mydb = connection()

        mycursor.execute('INSERT INTO linksespecificos(ALVO) VALUES ("'+ipLink+'")')
        mydb.commit()
        flash("LINK/IP inserido com sucesso")
        mycursor.close()
        mydb.close()
        gc.collect()
        return redirect(url_for("getIpLink"))
    return render_template("getIpLink.html", form=form)

except Exception as e:
    return(str(e))

@app.route('/getIpLink/')       
def getIpLink():
try:
    mycursor,mydb = connection()
    mycursor.execute('SELECT * FROM linksespecificos')
    data = mycursor.fetchall()
    mycursor.close()
    return render_template("getIpLink.html", listaIpLinks=data)
except Exception as e:
    return(str(e))  


@app.route('/getIpLink/<id>', methods=["GET","POST"])   
def deleteIpLink(id):
try:
    mycursor,mydb = connection()
    mycursor.execute('DELETE FROM linksespecificos WHERE ID="'+id+'"')
    mycursor.close()
    flash("Link deletado!")
    return redirect(url_for('getIpLink'))
except Exception as e:
    return(str(e))
```

Peço desculpas, porém estou começando agora na área e não tenho muito conhecimento, estou orgulhoso de ter chego até aqui, porém emperrei nessa parte. Se alguém puder ajudar, ficaria enormemente grato!

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo que vc faça assim:

```
consulta = "INSERT INTO linksespecificos(ALVO) VALUES (%s)"
cursor.execute(consulta,(ipLink,))

consulta = "DELETE FROM linksespecificos WHERE ID= %s"
cursor.execute(consulta,(id,))
```

mesmo que seja um parâmetro passado coloque uma virgula ao final.